# Nodejs, how to detect closed socket?

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, sockets

There is END event exist on net (TCP) sockets in nodejs, but nothing happens when it supposes to run:

```
socket.on('end', function(){
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
    });
```

I have read that there is `allowHalfOpen = true` property exists. Can any1 explain what does allowHalfOpen do, and how can I make this function detect any disconnections, even if window was close.

P.S. If that make s difference, I am making app in FLASH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.on('close') does listen to all kinds of disconnections, including unexpected once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using socket.on('disconnect')

Comment: socket.on('disconnect'), i did, doesn;t work when there is unexpected disconnect. But I tryed socket.on('close') - that works. but yet, not that smooth as I would expect.